# open a form if database search does not exist

Tags: database, search

hi all really appreciate the assist. after much research and tutorials i have created a sort of functioning pos form.

i can enter the barcode and then get the matching row from the database and update it into another table and update the datagrid.

how ever i am struggling with the following.

```
if the barcode is not found in the database, i want to open a search form which i have already created and search for the item and when i hit enter it must update my point of sale grid

also i want to create a running balance in a text box that adds the prices of all the item in my datagrid. i think i have to loop through the database each time and add all the values, but im thinking thats alot of processing each time i add and item.
    as you will see i am assigning the text box values to my insert into statement, i want to assign the variables i have created instead of the textbox values.
```

here is my code when i hit enter on the textbox..

Private Sub txtscan_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtscan.KeyDown

```
mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=fabpos"

Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
Dim bsource As New BindingSource

If (e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter) Then
    lbldescription.Text = ""
    lblprice.Text = ""
    lblbarcode.Text = ""
    lblqty.Text = ""
    lblstockcode.Text = ""
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Dim query1 As String = "Select * from inventory"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query1, mysqlconn)
        Dim dataset As New DataSet("posinvdetails")
        sda.SelectCommand = command
        sda.Fill(dbdataset)
        'sda.Fill(dataset)
        'loop through database and find record and assign variables to database values required
        For Each row As DataRow In dbdataset.Rows

            If row.Item("stockcode").ToString() = txtscan.Text Then
                Dim description As String = row.Item("description").ToString()
                Dim price As String = row.Item("spincl").ToString()
                Dim stockcode As String = row.Item("stockcode")
                Dim barcode As String = row.Item("barcode")
                Dim qty As String = 1
                lbldescription.Text = description
                lblprice.Text = price
                lblbarcode.Text = barcode
                lblqty.Text = qty
                lblstockcode.Text = stockcode
            End If
        Next

        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
        End Try

        'updating the details table
        mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
        mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=fabpos"
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

        Try
            mysqlconn.Open()
            Dim qryupdate As String

        qryupdate = "insert into fabpos.posinvdetails (stockcode,barcode,description,qty,price) values 
             ('" & lblstockcode.Text & "','" & lblbarcode.Text & "','" & lbldescription.Text &
                    "','" & lblqty.Text & "','" & lblprice.Text & "')"

        txtscan.Text = ""
            command = New MySqlCommand(qryupdate, mysqlconn)
            reader = command.ExecuteReader

            mysqlconn.Close()

        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Finally
            mysqlconn.Dispose()

        End Try

        ' finish updating posinvdetails table
    End If
'function to reload the datagrid
reloaddg()
```

enter image description here
shareeditdeleteflag